# Creating a dataset like the MNIST format, with different classes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I am looking to build a classification model using my own dataset. But I'm having trouble formatting the dataset to be used. They are currently in subfolders, with each name being the class. I want to create my dataset like the format of the MNIST dataset, but I am unable to do so. For example, for MNIST, we can split the dataset:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (
test_images,
test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

And then for example, I could flatten the data:

```
train_images = train_images.reshape((train_images.shape[0], -1))
test_images = test_images.reshape((test_images.shape[0], -1))
```

How would I replace `tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()` with my own dataset but in the same format as the MNIST dataset? I am also doing multi-class classification.

Edit: Added Notes:

To be clear, my main task is to replace the MNIST dataset with my own dataset: My subdirectories are like this for example:

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
......a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......b_image_1.jpg
......b_image_2.jpg
...class_c/
......c_image_1.jpg
......c_image_2.jpg
...class_d/
......d_image_1.jpg
......d_image_2.jpg
```

I tried following this [link](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) to make my dataset into a format that tf.keras could use to load the dataset, similar to the way the MNIST dataset is loaded. I have tried generating a tf.data.Dataset.

```
    data_dir = "/datas"
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
print(image_count)

cats = list(data_dir.glob('cats/*'))
PIL.Image.open(str(cats[0]))

batch_size = 32
img_height = 150
img_width = 150
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

But I am still unable to put it into the right format, to fix the code as described above. Something I saw was about conversion to a numpy array but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, [here are the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) from tensorflow about loading a directory of images

Comment: Yes, so I was following this link: https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/ , to try and create a dataset, but then I wasn't able to load a dataset and use the .load_data() function. Sorry, but I am still quite unfamiliar with producing and generating datasets. I am guessing .load_data() is for datasets they've already made.

Comment: What exactly do you call MNIST format?

Comment: It would help if you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing code for what you _actually_ tried, and the specific problem you ran into, so that we can offer specific help

Comment: Sure, I have added some further details...

Answer (score 0):

Some packages have helper functions to make data access easy for the users. As you can see in the documentation for the [load_data()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data) function, it returns a tuple of Numpy arrays:

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)

You can get the same structure by arranging your features (X) and target (y) as numpy arrays, and pass them through the [train_test_split()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html?highlight=train%20test%20split#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split) scikit-learn function.

Comment: how would it work for images, could you give me an example possibly... Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the parameter label_mode='categorical' when creating your train_ds and val_ds?

trainds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  label_mode='categorical',
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

Comment: This video has a detailed explanation how to set up the data sets to train TensorFlow models using Keras

Comment: Sorry which video?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFJeN9V1ZsI